# ListView Sorting

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I want to sort the listview data when click at the column header.
Found this article with the code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229643%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

but when run it, the first line

```
ColHeader clickedCol = (ColHeader)this.listView_ChkInOut.Columns[e.Column];
```

already generate error invalid cast exception was unhandled.

```
public class ColHeader : ColumnHeader
        {
            public bool ascending;
            public ColHeader(string text, int width, HorizontalAlignment align, bool asc)
            {
                this.Text = text;
                this.Width = width;
                this.TextAlign = align;
                this.ascending = asc;
            }
        }
```

I don't understand the code, can some explain why it had that error?

Comment: Apparently, `this.listView_ChkInOut.Columns[e.Column]` is not of type `ColHeader`.

Comment: So how should i write for the type colHeader?

Comment: Can you show implementation ColHeader class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        ColumnHeader lickedCol = (ColumnHeader)this.listView1.Columns[e.Column];
        MessageBox.Show(lickedCol.Text);
```

As far as i can see this should work properly.
At least i get the right text.

In the example you provided this happens when he added the Columnheaders

```
// parameter specifies true for an ascending sort order.
listView1.Columns.Add(new ColHeader("Name", 110, HorizontalAlignment.Left, true));
listView1.Columns.Add(new ColHeader("Region", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left, true));
listView1.Columns.Add(new ColHeader("Sales", 70, HorizontalAlignment.Left, true));
```

He added ColHeaders and not ColumnHeaders. I think you havent done this and then you get the error, at least this is what happend to me ;)

Comment: Yes. It did get the text.but the next code cannot be use. int numItems = this.listview_AvailableAsset.Items.Count; System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader does not contain a definistion for ascending

Comment: but my listview is generate from dataset, so how to set the parameter?

Comment: Do it programmatically ;). I don't know your code so i can't be more specific.

Comment: What if I want to make it sorting desc too?

Comment: Then i would change the bool ascending to false. you should look at the SortComparer class in the example you provided above :)

Comment: Boom, the code is working actually, just i didn't realize had comment of the code..